# dbx to databricks assets bundles

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-dbx, databricks-asset-bundle

We have been using dbx to manage and deploy databricks jobs. In dbx the command `dbx execute` is very useful during development when we can change stuff quickly and execute to check results. The execute command create a sort of sandbox to run the job.

Now that dbx is deprecated we want to use databricks assets bundles. Do we have anything similar? There seems to be just `deploy` option and it does have a dev mode but it actually creates a job in Workflow and then runs it.

Also using dbx we can execute and test individual task within a job and I don't seem to find anything similar in databricks assets bundles. Is there any workaround for this?